# Merging Date columns in Pandas dataframes with filtering conditions in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, merge

Have a tricky problem. I got two Pandas dataframes with datetime data in both of them, first one:

```
Date                   Number
2018-02-28 23:59:00     20
2018-03-01 00:37:00     35
2018-03-01 00:58:00     46
2018-03-01 02:14:00     11
2018-03-01 02:32:00     15
```

second one:

```
Date                   Value
2018-02-28 23:50:00     20
2018-02-28 23:51:00     35
2018-02-28 23:52:00     46
2018-02-28 23:53:00     11
2018-02-28 23:54:00     15
2018-02-28 23:55:00     20
2018-02-28 23:56:00     35
2018-02-28 23:57:00     46
2018-02-28 23:58:00     11
2018-02-28 23:59:00     15
2018-03-01 00:00:00     15
```

As you can already notice, the dates in first dataframe are just random dates and in the second dataframe they stored in order increasing on +1 minute each row.

What I try to achieve is to join the first dataframe on the second on date column but not like inner join style one-to-one but with a rule looking like this: you take the date from first dataframe (for example, '2018-02-28 23:59:00' and join twenty one rows from second dataframe -10 minutes from the date and +10 from the date (for this example, will be from '2018-02-28 23:49:00' to '2018-03-01 00:09:00').

I'm kind of confused-is there any Pandas filtering features that can help in achieving this kind of merging? Or maybe there is some pure pythonic solution.

Desired result will be the following:

```
Date1                      Date2                      Value
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-02-28 23:49:00        20                      
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-02-28 23:50:00        35               
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-02-28 23:51:00        46
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-02-28 23:52:00        15
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-02-28 23:53:00        20
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-02-28 23:54:00        35
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-02-28 23:55:00        46
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-02-28 23:56:00        11
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-02-28 23:57:00        15
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-02-28 23:58:00        20
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-02-28 23:59:00        35
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-03-01 00:00:00        46
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-03-01 00:01:00        11
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-03-01 00:02:00        15
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-03-01 00:03:00        20
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-03-01 00:04:00        35
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-03-01 00:05:00        46
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-03-01 00:06:00        11
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-03-01 00:07:00        15
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-03-01 00:08:00        20  
2018-02-28 23:59:00        2018-03-01 00:09:00        46
```

Thanks.

Comment: So for the example above, what would be the desired result?

Comment: made the edition

Comment: The `Values` in the second DataFrame go (in order): `20, 35, 46, 11, ...`. But the values in the desired DataFrame go `20, 35, 46, 15`. What is the logic which causes 11 to be skipped? or was it just a typo?

Comment: There are dates in the desired `Date2` column which are not in the (given) first or second DataFrame. How are the `Value`s being determined here?

Comment: Value is just randoms numbers they are not important at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with input like:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date1':[pd.datetime(2018,02,28, 23,59,00),pd.datetime(2018,03,01, 00,37,00)], 
                    'Number': [20,35]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date2':[pd.datetime(2018,02,28,23,50,00), pd.datetime(2018,02,28,23,51,00),pd.datetime(2018,03,01,00,42,00)], 
                    'Value':[20, 35, 46]})
```

First you can create a column `l_d2` in df1 with a list of all `Date2` within +/- 10 minutes of a `Date1` from `df1` such as (here is the filtering function you really need):

```
from datetime import timedelta
df1['l_d2'] = df1['Date1'].apply(lambda x: list(df2['Date2'][((x- timedelta(minutes=10)) <= df2['Date2']) & (df2['Date2'] <= (x + timedelta(minutes=10)))]))
```

Then you create a serie with `stack` function on this new column like:

```
s1 = df1.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['l_d2']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
s1.name = 'Date2' #same name as in df2 for merging after
```

And finally you can create the desire output `df_output` by joining `s1` with `df1`, dropping the column `l_d2` (not useful anymore) and merge with `df2` to add the column `Value`:

```
df_output = df1.drop('l_d2', axis=1).join(s1).merge(df2, on ='Date2')
```

The result with my inputs is like:

```
                Date1  Number               Date2  Value
0 2018-02-28 23:59:00      20 2018-02-28 23:50:00     20
1 2018-02-28 23:59:00      20 2018-02-28 23:51:00     35
2 2018-03-01 00:37:00      35 2018-03-01 00:42:00     46
```

Comment: gives a ValueError:columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Date'], dtype='object')

Comment: @HalfPintBoy I think your data in the column 'Date' is not the right type. Try to do: df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date']) (and same with df2) before doing anything

Comment: lsuffix='_Date', rsuffix='_Date' helped out